# AWS Classic load balancer route traffic to EC2 in another AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a query regarding a configuration regarding CLB and Availability zone.

When we create an Load balancer we have to specify the AZ's in which that ELB node will be created.

My question is can we have the CLB created in AZ A and have the EC2 instance in AZ B and without specifying the AZ B in CLB configuration and route traffic using route tables or any other configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is can we have the CLB created in AZ A and have the EC2 instance in AZ B and without specifying the AZ B in CLB configuration and route traffic using route tables or any other configuration

Sadly you **can't do this**. Load balancer will distribute traffic only to instance in AZs which it was enabled for.

Therefore, if you have CLB in **AZ A**, and your instance is in **AZ B**, the **instance will not** get any traffic.

[Cross-zone balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-disable-crosszone-lb.html) will **not help** either. It has different purpose, and will not distribute traffic to instances in AZ which are not included in CLB.

> With cross-zone load balancing, each load balancer node for your Classic Load Balancer distributes requests evenly across the registered instances in **all enabled Availability Zones**.

Therefore, your instances **must be located** in same AZs as those used for CLB